# In my WCF service, i need to call my void XXX method by passing credentials on security method

Tags: wcf

```
 [OperationContract]
 string Security(string userName, string Password);

 [OperationContract]
 void XXX(XXX);

 [OperationContract]
 void YYY(YYY);
```

In my **WCF service,** i need to call void XXX by passing credentials on security method

Answer (score 0):

Though you can pass credentials as parameters for each method (not to mention potentially insecure), it get's rather tedius.  Instead use WCF's custom user authentication behaviours.   They are invoked automatically each time a method (message is received really) is called.  It also makes methods cleaner as they are not populated with username/password everywhere.

MSDN:

> By default, when a user name and password is used for authentication, Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) uses Windows to validate the user name and password. However, WCF allows for custom user name and password authentication schemes, also known as validators. To incorporate a custom user name and password validator, create a class that derives from UserNamePasswordValidator and then configure it.

These behaviours operate irrespective of whether your service is `DataContract` or `MessageContract`.

These credentials are **encrypted** and stored in the **message headers** rather than in the message body itself where other parameters would normally reside.

### Stateless Service

The other problem of calling a service *once to authenticate*, and again to perform *some operation* is that you essentially force the service to be *stateful*, which you may not want.  By placing information regarding authentication along with the operation in the same message halves the messages sent; improves performance and more importantly the option of allowing your service to be stateless if so desired, possibly improving performance further still.

### Tell me more

- [How to: Use a Custom User Name and Password Validator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-a-custom-user-name-and-password-validator)

Comment: Curious what to make of this section: "By default [...] WCF [...] uses Windows to validate the user name and password". What is meant with "uses Windows"? Does it prompt for AD credentials? Or is it something different?

Comment: @Beltway _"Does it prompt for AD credentials?"_ -  it means [WCF will use Windows authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-a-custom-user-name-and-password-validator) using the username+password provided in the message.  It can be a domain account yes but there won't be any "prompt" as Windows has everything it needs.  Check out [Transport Security with Basic Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-basic-authentication)

Comment: Thanks. Noted it's stated on the original page but not until the very last section.

Comment: No worries.  I updated my comment to include a link to the _Transport Security with Basic Authentication_ page as that's what the case will be if the username+password is provided in the message....hopefully with _transport security_.    A better approach is [Transport Security with Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-windows-authentication) where **no username+password** is transmitted (securely or otherwise) at all.  Basically Kerberos ticket magic.  :)

Comment: I didn't know Windows auth was possible without Kerberos at all, hence the confusion.